# Property of Polymer object not triggering bindings from inside setInterval method

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, setinterval

I have a `<paper-progress>` bar that I want to use to show progress as time passes by. To update the value of the bar, I am using a recurrent method called `setInterval` to update a property of my `dom-module`. When I log the value of the property, I see that the value is being added correctly, but unfortunately my progress bar isn't moving. It is as if the change in the property isn't being caught by the data binding set on the bar attributes. A much reduced code follows below to exemplify it.

```
<dom-module id="x-test">
    <template>
        <paper-progress
          value="{{progresso.value}}"
          min="{{progresso.min}}"
          max="{{progresso.max}}"
          class="transiting">
        </paper-progress>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-test',
      properties: {
        progresso: {
            type: Object,
            value: {
                min: 0,
                max: 10000,
                value: 0
            }
        }
      },
      attached: function(){
        var timer = setInterval(this.count,1000);
      },
      count: function(){
        var progresso = document.querySelector('test').progresso;
        try {
          if (progresso.value < progresso.max) {
            progresso.value = progresso.value + 100;
          } else {
            progresso.value = progresso.max;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
        }
      }
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

What am I missing? What do I have to do in order for the `<paper-progress>` element to see the changes in the `progresso` property of the `dom-module`? Both elements are inside the same module.

**P.S.:**

- I omitted the `clearInterval()` from the snippet above; but it is included in the code.
- I don't know if it could have any influence, but the actual Javascript code is inside a behavior that I have added to the polymer object.

**Edited:** I made some mistakes while copying and pasting the code. I modified the code above to reflect the real one. Also added a few more comments to make my situation a little more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Notifying Subproperty Updates

When you have a [data binding to a subproperty](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notify-path), setting the subproperty directly won't automatically update the data binding. You either have to manually call `this.notifyPath(SUBPROPERTY_PATH)`:

```
this.progresso.value = 20;
this.notifyPath('progresso.value');
```

...or use `this.set(SUBPROPERTY_PATH, VALUE)`.

```
this.set('progresso.value', 20);
```

#### Element Naming

It looks like you're trying to define a custom element named `test`, but the Web Components spec [requires the element name be hyphenated](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#register-element), so the name should be something like `x-test`:

```
<dom-module id="x-test">
  <template>...</template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-test',
      ...
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

#### Declaring Polymer method

To declare a method on your Polymer object, specify the desired method name followed by a colon and then the function expression:

```
Polynmer({
  // this.count: function() {  // DON'T DO THIS
  count: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

#### Querying DOM

Note that `document.querySelector()` queries the entire document instead of your Polymer element. Querying the document can be problematic because you could have multiple instances of the element in the document (requiring you to apply classes or IDs to the element for selection if you're after a specific element), and `document.querySelector()` cannot query the element's shadow DOM.

From a Polymer method, you should instead use `this.$$(SELECTOR)` (or `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(SELECTOR)`), which works for both Shady DOM (default in Polymer 1) or Shadow DOM (default in Polymer 2).

```
var myEl = this.$$('a-class-in-my-element');
```

*Note: it turns out you don't need to query for the element at all (see **Accessing Element Property**).*

#### Accessing Element Property

Since `progresso` is a property of your Polymer object, you could access it directly off `this` (e.g., `this.progresso`) from your Polymer method, so `count()` should look like this:

```
count: function() {
  // var progresso = document.querySelector('test').progresso;   // DON'T DO THIS
  var progresso = this.progresso;
  ...
}
```

#### Initializing `Object` Property

To initialize the value of an `Object` property, make sure to [use a function that returns the intial value](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configure-values). Otherwise, all instances of your element would share the same `Object`, which can cause unintentional side effects.

```
Polymer({
  ...
  properties: {
    progresso: {
      type: Object,
      value: function() {
        return {min: 0, max: 10000, value: 0};
      }
    }
  }
});
```

#### Binding Callback Context

Note that you need to bind the context of your `setInterval` callback so that it refers to your Polymer object (so that your callback's `this` refers to the Polymer object instead of the outer context, which is normally the `Window` object).

```
attached: function() {
  setInterval(this.count.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

#### Cleaning Up on Detach

Assuming you could detach your element, you should add cleanup in `detached` to stop the interval timer that was started in `attached`:

```
attached: function() {
  this._timerId = setInterval(...);
},
detached: function() {
  clearInterval(this._timerId);
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-test',
    properties: {
      progresso: {
        type: Object,
        value: () => ({
          min: 0,
          max: 10000,
          value: 0
        })
      }
    },
    attached: function() {
      this._timerId = setInterval(this.count.bind(this), 1000);
    },
    detached: function() {
      clearInterval(this._timerId);
    },
    count: function() {
      const progresso = this.progresso;
      if (progresso.value < progresso.max) {
        this.set('progresso.value', progresso.value + 100);
        console.log('value', progresso.value);
      } else {
        this.set('progresso.value', progresso.max);
        clearInterval(this._timerId);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.9.3/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-progress/paper-progress.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-test></x-test>

  <dom-module id="x-test">
    <template>
      <style>
        paper-progress {
          --paper-progress-height: 20px;
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
      <paper-progress
          value="{{progresso.value}}"
          min="{{progresso.min}}"
          max="{{progresso.max}}"
          class="transiting">
       </paper-progress>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/egqaBz?editors=1010)

Comment: Hello Tony, thanks a lot for your thorough explanation.
 - While pasting the code here, I made a couple of mistakes; I have fixed them now.
 - I have a problem with using `this.$$` and with **accessing element property** because my callback function `count` is being called inside the `Window` scope, not the Polymer object scope. This is why I used the `document.querySelector` (in the actual code I use an id to avoid selecting any other elements).

Comment: - I'll take a look at what you said about **notifying subproperties** changes, change the way I initialize the object, use `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(SELECTOR)` instead of `document.querySelector`;
 - I'll also change the callback context to be able to use `this` at the polymer object. 

I'll come back with updates. But thank you for now.

Comment: Just did the modifications and it works!!! You are the master Tony. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @FTM No problem :)